# WHM/Cpanel New Account issue - Edit DNS Zone error

Tags: dns, whm

I have created an account through WHM, but never had this issue.  The error I get when I try to edit the zone is:

```html
There were errors in the zone which have been highlighted below. Please manually correct these errors before trying to edit the zone. 
; cPanel first:11.60.0.28 (update_time):1483209424 11.60.0.28: Cpanel::ZoneFile::VERSION:1.3 hostname:s132-148-23-168.secureserver.net latest:11.60.0.28
; Zone file for wonderlandsigns.com
$TTL 14400
@      86400 IN      SOA     ns1.secureserver.net. info.. ( near 'info..': empty label
  2016123101 ; serial, todays date+todays
  3600  ; refresh, seconds
  7200  ; retry, seconds
  1209600  ; expire, seconds
  86400 )  ; minimum, seconds

wonderlandsigns.com. 86400 IN NS ns1.secureserver.net.
wonderlandsigns.com. 86400 IN NS ns2.secureserver.net.


wonderlandsigns.com. IN A 132.148.23.168

wonderlandsigns.com. IN MX 0 wonderlandsigns.com.

mail IN CNAME wonderlandsigns.com.
www IN CNAME wonderlandsigns.com.
ftp IN CNAME wonderlandsigns.com.
```

How do I manually edit it to fix the issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this with multiple ways such as using WinSCP OR Putty. Here is the simplest way doing it via WinSCP

**WinSCP**

- Download & Run WinCP
- Use your server IP, Username & Password to login to server
- Go to the following path /var/named
- Find your domain file within directory, double click to open and edit
- Save the file
- Restart DNS Server

Hope this helps!

Comment: Followed the steps and was able to login to my server, switched to su -, but get "Permission Denied" when I try to edit the file.  Any thoughts?

Comment: Are you logging to server as root user? OR Try WinSCP instead of SSH

Comment: I tried both ways, through putty and WinSCP with root access

Comment: Thanks for you help.  I did fix the problem using SSH and the nano command to edit the file.  All works now.

Comment: That Great, nice to here that :)